Steric factor in Harpoon mechanism
According to Wikipedia

The main feature of these (harpoon reactions) redox reactions is that, unlike most reactions, they have steric factors greater than unity; that is, they take place faster than predicted by collision theory. This is explained by the fact that the colliding particles have greater cross sections than the pure geometrical ones calculated from their radii, because when the particles are close enough, an electron "jumps" (therefore the name) from one of the particles to the other one, forming an anion and a cation which subsequently attract each other.


Following is sourced from here

Under its (coloumbic interactions) influence the ions move together (the line is wound in), the reaction takes place, and $\ce{KBr}$ and $\ce{Br}$ emerge. The harpoon extends the cross-section for the reactive encounter and we would greatly underestimate the reaction rate if we used for the collision cross-section the value for simple mechanical contact between $\ce{K}$ and $\ce{Br2}$

Fig. 5: Energy is not the only criterion of a successful reactive encounter, for relative orientation may also play a role. (a) In this collision, the reactants approach in an inappropriate relative orientation, and no reaction occurs even though their energy is sufficient, (b) In this encounter, both the energy and the orientation are suitable for reaction.



Why do we assume a cylindrical surface as molecules are striking and coming off and volume/solid angle is a more appropriate term?
When is the steric factor considered as the fraction of molecules with proper orientation? (I think proper orientation is not possible with such a simplified assumption of cylindrical cross-section)
When is it considered as the ratio of reactive and geometric cross-sections?


Following is an example on harpoon reactions from the book-Physical chemistry by Peter Atkins

Estimating a steric factor
Estimate the value of $P$ for the harpoon mechanism by calculating the distance at which it becomes energetically favourable for the electron to leap from $\ce{K}$ to $\ce{Br2}$. Take the sum of the radii of the reactants (treating them as spherical) to be $\pu{400pm}$
Collect your thoughts Begin by identitying all the energy as involved in the electron transfer process $\ce{K + Br2 -> K^+ + Br2^-}$. There are three terms: the first is the ionization energy, $I$ of $\ce{K}$; the second is the electron affinity, $E_\mathrm{ea}$ of $\ce{Br2}$; and the third is the Coulombic interaction energy between the ions when they have been formed. When the separation of the ions is $R$, the Coulombic attraction energy is $-e^2/4\pi\varepsilon_0 R$. The electron flips across when the sum of these three contributions changes from positive to negative (that is, when the sum becomes zero) so making the process energetically favourable.
The solution The net change in energy when the transfer occurs at a separation $R$ is $$E = I - E_\mathrm{ea} - \frac{e^2}{4\pi\varepsilon_0 R}$$
This energy is zero when $R$ is equal to some critical value $R^*$ (and is negative for smaller values of $R$) $$0 = I - E_\mathrm{ea} - \frac{e^2}{4\pi\varepsilon_0 R^*}$$ rearranges to $$R^*= \frac{e^2}{4\pi\varepsilon_0 (I-E_\mathrm{ea})}$$
When the particles are at this separation, the harpoon shoots across from $\ce{K}$ to $\ce{Br2}$. The reactive cross-section can therefore be identified as $\sigma^* = \pi R^{*2}$. The non-reactive collision cross-section is $\sigma = \pi d^2$, where $d = R(\ce{K})+R(\ce{Br2})$ is the sum of the radii of the (assumed) spherical reactants. These values of $\sigma$ and $\sigma^*$ imply that the steric factor is $$P = \frac{\sigma^*}{\sigma} = \frac{\pi R^{*2}}{\pi d^2} = \left\{\frac{e^2}{4\pi\varepsilon_0 d(I-E_\mathrm{ea})}\right\}^2$$
With $I = 420\pu{kJ mol-1}$ (corresponding to $0.70\pu{aJ}$), $E_\mathrm{ea} = 250\pu{kJ mol-1}$ (corresponding to $0.42 \pu{aJ}$), and $d = 400 \pu{pm}$, the value of $P$ is $4.2$, in good agreement with the experimental value ($4.8$).



When is the steric factor considered as the ratio of reactive cross-section and non-reactive cross-section?

Why is the "non-reactive" collision cross-section set as sum of the radii of the reactant molecules? Collision isn't occuring at the first place

"The harpoon extends the cross-section for the reactive encounter and we would greatly underestimate the reaction rate if we used for the collision cross-section the value for simple mechanical contact between $\ce{K}$ and $\ce{Br2}$" is this the non-reactive collision cross-section the question was talking about?

And how does the ratio relate to being the orientation for the same?


Wikipedia has described the steric factor as the ratio of cross-sections and the orientation as well, but I am unable to connect and to me, they feel independent from each other:-

When two discrete particles interact in classical physics, their mutual cross section is the area transverse to their relative motion within which they must meet in order to scatter from each other. If the particles are hard inelastic spheres that interact only upon contact, their scattering cross section is related to their geometric size. If the particles interact through some action-at-a-distance force, such as electromagnetism or gravity, their scattering cross section is generally larger than their geometric size.


I would look separately into the definition of collisional cross-sections to understand the units used (unit area), see eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_section_(physics)

Br2 can be modeled as having a cylindrical shape (or, as in Atkins, a sphere) under collisions, K as a sphere. If the angle and location of incidence matter you can still speak of an effective cross-section and evaluate this from the experimental data. When an electron hops a productive collision is guaranteed (or greatly enhanced).
